# Java script addEventListnere to keypress event

Tags: javascript, keypress

I have an input form on a [website](https://profil.tlen.pl/rejestracja/) with a login Id field

```
<input type="text" id="login" value maxlength="25">
```

I want to fill this field with javascript.

```
var login = document.getElementById('login');
login.addEventListener('keypress', myScript(), false);
function myScript(){
    loginId.value = 'aliyakhan891';
    var query = login.value;
}
```

the problem is that i have tried different event handling code but it does not work properly.

I tried  `app.request(query);` but it also doesn't work. what is the proper way to handle this event.

please visit the [site](https://profil.tlen.pl/rejestracja/) to check that field.

Comment: `login.addEventListener('keypress', myScript, false);`

Comment: @gurinder372  why do you marked this question as duplicate? if you really think this is duplicated provide link to that original question. it's so urgent and i am working on this for last 5 hours. please  help me with this

Comment: this is just for testing/learning purpose

Comment: The first comment above from Isaac gave you the solution.